# Arguments Optional FreeCodeCamp Challenge

Tags: javascript, arguments, currying

in need of help with a codecamp challenge:

**Arguments Optional** - The challenge

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/arguments-optional

**My Question**

I know this can be done with the arguments object (see figure 1), where I can call the function again when the second value is undefined so I've gone for a different approach; However, my code of using currying works but becomes an issue with 'addTogether(5)(7);'

**Issue ->**
I get the returned value of 12 but doesn't get approved in the code challenge.

I did originally return the value inside the sum function but the challenge required the sum value to be returned in addTogether function, which I did so now it resulting in the following

- addTogether(2,3); // now working
- addTogether(5)(7); // NOT working
- addTogether(23, 30); // now working

Is there something I'm doing wrong that's resulting in the test case failing even though the correct value is returned?

```
let val = 0;

function sum(a, b) { 
  val = a + b;
}


function sumTwoAnd(sumFunc) {
 
    return function addTogether(...params) { 

      let numsArr = [...params];

      const res = numsArr.every(el => typeof el === 'number');
      if (res === false) return;
  
      if (numsArr.length >= sumFunc.length) { 

        sumFunc(...numsArr);

      } else { 

        return function(...args2) {  

          let newArr = numsArr.concat(args2);
          addTogether(...newArr);

      }
    }
    console.log(val);
    return val; 
  }
}


let addTogether = sumTwoAnd(sum);

addTogether(2,3);
addTogether(5)(7);
addTogether(23, 30);
```

**Figure 1**

Shows how I can get 'test(5)(7)' the second parameter from the function

```
function test()  { 
  const [f, s] = arguments;
  console.log(f, s)
  if (s === undefined) { 
    return s => test(f, s)
  }
  
}

test(23, 30);
test(5)(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared `addTogether` using `let`, so [the declaration won't be hoisted above the point where it was defined.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) This is making your recursive call in the `else` statement fail, since `addTogether()` doesn't exist that far up.

You might want to extract the function you're returning in `sumTwoAnd()` as a separate function definition, so it can freely call itself, similar to your Figure 1 example.

Or you can call `sumTwoAnd()` instead to regain the function, then pass `newArr` to said function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the function I have now returned it...

```
return addTogether(...newArr);
```

This now works :)